# Create multiple instances of same dependency w/ different configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, autofac

I have an application (**IJobInit**) that uses a list from JSON settings to create multiple instances of a class (**IJob**). This class does some work using two other dependencies, **IInputClient** and **IOutputClient**. It uses M.Extensions.DependencyInjection to create a container which is handed off to AutoFac to create an IContainer.

```cs
IJobInit(IContainer container)
```

I would like IInputClient to be configured different for each instance of IJob. Speficially, I'd like to pass in a secret for it to use. The result would be:

```cs
IInputClient(HttpClient client)
```

where HttpClient is configured using [ConfigureHttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.configurehttpclient?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_HttpClientBuilderExtensions_ConfigureHttpClient_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IHttpClientBuilder_System_Action_System_IServiceProvider_System_Net_Http_HttpClient__) such that IJob does not know that it is pre-authenticated. This would also be suitable:

```cs
IInputClient(ISecretProvider secretsProvider, string secretName)
```

The end result is three instances of IJob with IInputClient configured differently.

```cs
IJob(IInputClient inputClient1, IOutputClient outputClient)
IJob(IInputClient inputClient2, IOutputClient outputClient)
IJob(IInputClient inputClient3, IOutputClient outputClient)
```

How do I achieve this?  I was looking at Autofac scopes but those controlwhen an instance is created without any control over its configuration (unless I missed it).

A colleague suggested that I could host each instance of IJob in its own process with its own configuration which *is* possible but I'm trying to host all the jobs in a single Azure Function and use the list in config to create the inner jobs.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you've inverted your control which is causing the problem.  If you had an enumerable configuration then create your enumerable of `IJobInit/IJob` based on the number of configurations.  Autofac supports [Enumerated relationships implicitly](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b).

Comment: Also it looks like you have multiple Containers... those types of configurations are really rare, I don't see why this would be needed for your implementation.  On second inspection, you may need to create another abstraction layer for your `IInputClient` replacing `HttpClient` with an object that knows about the secret implementation although you could use [pre-configuring named instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#named-clients) but I'm not sure that would get you what you need.

Comment: I do like the enumerated relationships.  I think I could use Autofac's providers to programmatically register them too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally happy with this solution but it works for now.

```cs
        private async Task<IInputClient> GetClientAsync(string secretId)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = this.httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            string secret = await this.secretsProvider.GetSecretAsync(secretId);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Concat(":", secret))));

            return this.scope.Resolve<IInputClient>(new TypedParameter(typeof(HttpClient), httpClient));
        }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `IInputClient` as a dependency for whatever class this method is on?

Comment: I do.  I use the client created in this method to create a list of `IProcessor(IInputClient, IOutputClient)` and then run through them.

```IInputClient client = await this.GetClientAsync(this.GetKeyVaultSecretUri(kvp.Key));
var proc = this.scope.Resolve<Processor>(new NamedParameter("inputClient", client));
```

Comment: you keep using Resolve.  Using Dependency Injection you should rarely ever need to resolve anything manually....

Comment: I don't disagree.  The docs describe an [IRegistrationSource](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html) which *almost* does what I need but it returns A,B,C where I want A, A', A'', A''' and so on.

Comment: I think if I could dynamically register instances to the container before (or after) it gets built I could use the enumerator feature to simplify.  EDIT: Maybe RegistrationSource can do that, though I would still need to call resolve in the activator.  I'd need to do some more research and experimentation.  (still relatively new to all this!)